# Why swaggerUI can not display method parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have a problem which when I am using a metod with parameter  just like AddProduct method with parameter but I can not see this parameter in SwaggerUI , what am i doing wrong ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding `[FromBody]` on the parameter?

Comment: Just try this but not working , is this use True =>



[HttpPost, Route("AddProduct")]
        public void AddProduct([FromBody] Product product)
        {
            IProductService productService = new ProductService(new EfProductDal());
            productService.AddProduct(product);
        }

Comment: You defined a POST request, which has a request `body` - the request body contains the items within `Product`, so as far as I can tell, the Swagger generated is correct.  ASP.NET Web API framework automatically interprets reference types defined in a method signature to come from the request body of an HTTP request.

Comment: Everything is there, but it is a POST and your class will be filled by a body. In your screenshot the example value contains the properties of the Product class. If you click on the "Try it out" button you could edit the body and send the data. So nothing is wrong and works as expected.